# Where is defined the Place Order button in default checkout payment step section?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, template, magento2.2

I wanted to know where the button from the image is defined (The place order button in the payment step of checkout)

And also where is the discount code section defined?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each payment, it defines its own the place order button, for example, for Cash On Delivery payment: `vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html`.

For the discount: `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/payment/discount.html`.

We need to override these templates.

Comment: Thanks for your replies ! How Do I know the type of payement ?

Comment: You can go to admin `STORE > Configuration > SALES > Payment Methods`, you can see the payment methods. If you want to see some payment methods code, you can take a look at the `vendor/magento` folder. You can find some offline payment methods: `vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/Model`

Answer (score 2):

Place order button filepath comes from Checkout module:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/review/actions/default.html
```

Apply discount code field comes from template file,

```
vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/payment/discount.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the **Place order for zero subtotal** method in file :

`vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/free.html`

and after static content deploy it will go under

`pub/static/frontend/{package}/{theme}/en_US/Magento_Payment/template/payment/free.html`

And for the discount:

`vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/payment/discount.html`

and after static content deploy it will go under

`pub/static/frontend/{package}/{theme}/en_US/Magento_SalesRule/template/payment/discount.html`