# Magento2 : Extra Checkout Step after Review & Payments Section with Place Order Button

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

I have added custom checkout step after **Review and Payment**, all steps are working fine but issue is **Place Order** button display on **Review and Payment**.

How to move **Place Order** button to last added custom step and add continue button to **Review and Payment** step.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Did you find any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

> magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\review\actions\default.html

You need to override above file

> magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\default.js

`placeOrder: function (data, event)`

[Where is defined the Place Order button in default checkout payment step section?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144667/where-is-defined-the-place-order-button-in-default-checkout-payment-step-section)

[Magento 2: How to override mini-cart default template html file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96540/magento-2-how-to-override-mini-cart-default-template-html-file)

[how to override template files for magento2 extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108788/how-to-override-template-files-for-magento2-extension)

Comment: How I can add continue button to Payment and Review step?

Comment: @SHPatel Have you solved this? Please answer if you get solution.

Comment: Yes I completed this one I will shortly post this answer.

Comment: Hello @SureshChikani, can you please post your answer, I have also the same issue